# how to retrieve the the style.top with DOM,is there any other way?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

i specified a div with a ID of testBox:

```
<div id="testBox"></div>
```

and style it in the head section :

```
#testBox {
        background: red;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
            }
```

then at the bottom of the body,i put the JS :

```
var box = document.getElementById("testBox");
        console.log(box.style.left);
        console.log(box.style.width);
```

use the FireBug in FireFox ,but it just tell me:

> it's an empty string....

But when i put the style infomation in the div tag like this:

```
<div id="testBox" style="background: red;width: 25px;height: 25px;"></div>
```

then the JS could do its work,retrieve all the information i want

so is this the only way to get the style information whit it all inline ,or i just miss something,after all i am just new to the JS and DOM ....

Comment: Your javascript code should be run when the DOM is ready or page fully loaded (event onLoad of body tag).Is this true?

Comment: i have test this using `window.onload = getBoxStyle`,but still get the same problem.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `box.id` what is returned to you is the `id` attribute of the box element as declared in your html.

When you say `box.style` you are accessing a javascript object also created based on your markup.

Styling attributes that are not defined inline are not used when the dom-representation of the style attribute is created.

Here is an [article](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/dhtmlcascade.shtml) which highlights this behaviour.

However, if you use a library like jQuery you can do

```
$(function(){alert($("#textBox").css("width"));});
```

and this will give you your css value.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to AVD for pointing me in the right direction:
Here is a method which uses his solution but adds support for IE < 9:

```
var box = document.getElementById("testBox");
var style = window.getComputedStyle ? window.getComputedStyle(box) : box.currentStyle;

alert("Height : " + style["height"]);
alert("Width : " + style["width"]);
alert("Left : " + style["left"]);
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2Sj5/1/).

Comment: Thank you! i see the point,but without the Library like jQuery ,is there any method provided by JavaScript could help me to get the style information?

Comment: I am not aware of such method.

Comment: fine, i have test out.To get cross browser i really should using the jQuery.... Thank you again !

Comment: @strangeline See the update. AVD's method with added support for IE

Comment: it's really good one ! since i am new here i have no enough reputation to vote for this answer, but you really help me a lot ,thank you anyway!

Comment: @strangeline Hm, this is strange. You should be able to accept the answer by clicking on this green tick next to it.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle). It gives the final used values of all the CSS properties of an element.

```
var box = document.getElementById("testBox");
var style=window.getComputedStyle(box);
console.log("Height : " + style["height"]);
console.log("Width : " + style["width"]);
console.log("Left : " + style["left"]);
```